# how to make float element not move around

Tags: html, css

Right now, I have two float elements sitting next to each other. One `float:left`, one `float:right`. I have set `min-width` for the left side so that the elements don't overlap when I resize the screen to smaller size. Right now when I make it small, the right element would just flow to the bottom of the left element. How do I make the right element sit in place and resizeable?

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with your code?

Comment: You want them to always stay on 1 line? ... and when not fit, scroll vertical?

Comment: If you explain better what you want to achieve and post code along with maybe an image showing the expected result, you will get a proper answer instead of now, a bunch of guesses (some more qualified than other)

Comment: I am trying to fix someone else's work, and its a huge chunk of html, not so easy to post or copy. What I have now on the left side is a search results menu which will float as I scroll up and down, and on the right side, I have the information selected. As I resize the window though, the right side floats to the bottom of the left side, I want it to always stay in one place.

Comment: For future users to know, and as you are supposed to do, it would be great if you could accept an answer, if any, that best helped you solve your question.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't accept the answer that helped you solve your question? ... We here at SO put our own free time to help you and others, and I think it would be appropriate doing that, don't you think so?

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block;` on elements and remember not to put any whitespace between them. There's a nice tutorial [here](http://learnlayout.com/inline-block-layout.html).

But, with the min-width, your div will clear. In such case try to use flexbox.

For flex container you could use something like this:

```
.flex-container {
        display: inline-flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-content: stretch;
        align-items: flex-start;
    }
```

And for your divs, something like this.

```
.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
    min-width: 150px;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
    order: 0;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    align-self: auto;
}
```

```css
.flex-container {
  background: black;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  align-items: flex-start;
  padding: 20px;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  background: yellow;
  order: 0;
  height: 150px;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  align-self: auto;
  min-width: 150px;
}
.flex-item:nth-child(2) {
  background: green;
  height: 150px;
  order: 0;
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  width: 100px;
  align-self: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
  <div class="flex-item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This won't work using only `display: inline-block`, because as soon as the min width kicks in, it will break line

Comment: LGSon - you are right, with min-width, the element flows to the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

Here is 3 solutions, all keeping the `.left` and `.right` element in 1 row,

first `display: table` if you need to make it work on both older and newer browsers

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}
.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.right {
  display: table-cell;
  background: lightgray;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

second, `flexbox` for newer browsers (recommended)

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgray;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text 
  </div>
</div>
```

---

third, `display: inline-block` + `white-space: nowrap` (work on both older and newer browsers)

```css
.wrapper {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.left {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
  min-width: 160px;
  background: lightgray;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  background: lightgray;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  white-space: normal;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
    Left menu item<br>
  </div><div class="right">
    Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text Right content text 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `display:inline-block` instead of float to bring two elements on one line. Try it, create a class add this css-code into it. Define a width and height and you get the same effect.

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  border: 1px black dotted;
  padding: 10px 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">A box</div>
<div class="box">Second Box</div>
```

Never forget to set a `height`, too. If you forget this and they have different heights, they moving out of control. ;)

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot =)

Comment: @CJ408: It would be nice, to mark this as an answer if this answer helped you and answered your question. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Do not float the right element. It will take the remaining space.

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  min-width: 400px;
}
#right {
  overflow: hidden; /* Establish formatting context */
  /* It's a good idea to set some min-width */
}
```

```html
<div id="left">Left</div>
<div id="right">Right</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try using flexbox. I started with it like week ago and it is pretty powerful.

Maybe something like this.

https://jsfiddle.net/o0nb6as0/

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: left;
}

.left {
  height: 100px;
  min-width: 200px;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
  background: #888;
}

.right {
    height: 100px;
    background: #aaa;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">
  I am left and have min width.
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    I am right and have flexible width.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: does flex box follow you around tho? because what I have on the left side is a float menu which helps me navigate, and the right element is much longer than the left one